# Trigger on MouseHover?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, mousehover

I was wondering if there was a way to setup a trigger on `MouseHover`, not `MouseOver`.

I would like an action to occur when the user keeps their mouse over a specified area for X seconds instead of when they just MouseOver it in passing.

Comment: Something as simple as a ToolTip (for which the time is configurable), or do you actually need to do something that requires an actual Action and/or Trigger?

Comment: @Wonko: I want to enlarge the control when the mouse is hovered over it for X seconds. I want the rest of the controls to resize according to the size of the Resized control, so I can't just put the resized control in the ToolTip. I might be able to do something hackish with the ToolTip though, hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `IsMouseOver` trigger begin after X seconds, you should be able to use a Storybard and set the `BeginTime` Property. Here's an example for a `Button` which increases its size by 50% when the mouse is hovering it for 2 seconds.
To skip the animation part you can set `Duration="0"` for the `DoubleAnimation`s

```
<Button Content="Button"
        Height="23"
        Width="75"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:02">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.5"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.0"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction. I ended up animating the height on my object instead of the scale since I wanted other controls to adjust based on this object's size. I actually have the whole thing in an AttachedProperty now, so am very happy :)

Comment: You can also animate (Control.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY) instead of RenderTransform to achieve similar result